# I get an error when creating a virtualenv. The error says something about python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

I get the following error when trying to create virtualenv.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant$ virtualenv test2
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in test2/bin/python3
Also creating executable in test2/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 832, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 994, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1427, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
OSError: [Errno 71] Protocol error: 'python3' -> 'test2/bin/python'
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant$
```

I also get an error when trying to enter the virtualenv. Neither of my following attempts work:

```
source test2/bin/activate
source test2/bin/python/activate
source test2/bin/python3/activate
```

Comment: I don't understand what I should do to resolve this. Can you please help me? The top rated reply is to use --always-copy. When and why should I use this?

Comment: If you need to know where to use `--always-copy`, you might want to do some research before you use vagrant and virtualenv. There's only once place where you can use `--always-copy` here anyway; try that.

Answer (score 7):

You either need to add the --always-copy flag and the end of virtualenv test2 or run virtualenv test2 outside of the /vagrant folder.